# How can I get rid of the bold setting the text?

Tags: css, text, formatting

I have h1 h2 and a for the text formatting.

In fact....h2 and a are identical,but I'd like to change a to non-bold text.

How can I do that?

here is my what I have put together so far:http://jsbin.com/tifuhute/44/

Comment: `font-weight: normal;`

Comment: There are no `<a>` elements in the jsbin you provided...What exactly are you trying to change?

Comment: Sorry....just changed it, but it is acting weird. The padding doesnt seem to be where it should be....although it has it at 15 px.

Comment: So you no longer need to change the weight of the text but now the padding? If that's the case, I would recommend posting a new question asking for help with that issue.

Comment: yeah, it seems so. font-weight normal sorted it out. Thanks.

Comment: Also, why are you using an anchor tag for something that isn't a link? You should use `<p>` or `<span>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Set `font-weight: normal;`
to your css class:

```
#text h2 {
    color: #151515;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: you can also just do `h1, h2, h3, h4 ,h5, h6 { font-weight:normal }` to effect every header in your document. By default your browser should render header tags as bold, so you have to override it.